# Zombie process running xlwings

Tags: xlwings

I get a python error when attempting to use xlwings.  Just importing xlwings seems to be sufficient to trigger the problem.

```
Lewis-MacBook-Air:~ lewis$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import xlwings
>>> xlwings.__version__
'0.6.0'
>>> exit()
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 47, in clean_up
    if is_excel_running():
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 98, in is_excel_running
    if proc.name() == 'Microsoft Excel':
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 539, in name
    cmdline = self.cmdline()
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 592, in cmdline
    return self._proc.cmdline()
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 209, in wrapper
    raise ZombieProcess(self.pid, self._name, self._ppid)
ZombieProcess: psutil.ZombieProcess process still exists but it's a zombie (pid=71)
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 47, in clean_up
    if is_excel_running():
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 98, in is_excel_running
    if proc.name() == 'Microsoft Excel':
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 539, in name
    cmdline = self.cmdline()
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 592, in cmdline
    return self._proc.cmdline()
  File "/Users/lewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 209, in wrapper
    raise ZombieProcess(self.pid, self._name, self._ppid)
psutil.ZombieProcess: psutil.ZombieProcess process still exists but it's a zombie (pid=71)
Lewis-MacBook-Air:~ lewis$
```

Calling python from Excel using Workbook.caller() is working fine.

I am running El Capitan 10.11.2 (Beta 5).

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the version `3.3.0` of `psutil` is causing this, as logged [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/315).

At the moment, downgrading to `pip install psutil==3.2.2` should help until this is fixed.

**update**:
This has been fixed with v0.6.1